# Error if datatype 'json' is specified

Tags: jquery, json

I have the following jQuery Code:

```
$.post('php/php_result.php', {'functions':'getpersonaldetails','theuserid':data1}, function(data3, status3) {
    var personalDetails = JSON.parse(data3)[0];
    alert(personalDetails.last_name);           
},'json');
```

The above code has en `Syntax Error: JSON.parse: unexpected chacter at line1 column 2 of the JSON data`. If I remove the datatype `json`, the `alert` works fine.

My PHP:

```
$queryStmt = "SELECT merch_id, last_name, first_name, middle_name, birthday, contact_no, address FROM merchandiser WHERE merch_id=:userId";
$queryPrepare = $dba_connect->prepare($queryStmt);
$queryPrepare->execute(array(':userId'=>$_POST['theuserid']));
$queryResult = $queryPrepare->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$queryPrepare->closeCursor();
$jsonResponse = json_encode($queryResult);
echo $jsonResponse;
```

Why am I having error when I indicate `json` as my datatype?

Comment: `var personalDetails = data3[0];`

Comment: @Tomalak  it's not about posting json data to somewhere.It's about parsing json response into jQuery post coming from server.Please read question once.

Comment: Then this is your duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4064444/returning-json-from-a-php-script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you instruct jQuery to expect JSON, it'll [decode it for you automatically](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> `"json"`: **Evaluates the response as JSON and returns a JavaScript
>   object**. Cross-domain `"json"` requests are converted to `"jsonp"` unless
>   the request includes jsonp: false in its request options. The JSON
>   data is parsed in a strict manner; any malformed JSON is rejected and
>   a parse error is thrown.

Thus parsing it again is not going to work.

Just let the framework do the job for you.